# SQL query dosnt show the right result

Tags: html, mysql, sql

Im making a hotel website. Right now, im working on a page where the user enters 2 dates, and a sql query checks if there is any available rooms. I've entered a booking in there myself, and I have tested the query in MYSQL console, and it works. However, I cant get it to work on my website.

```
<?php
$sql = "
SELECT romnummer
FROM rom
WHERE rom.id NOT IN 
(
    SELECT rom_id 
    FROM   bestilling B
           JOIN tilgjengelse RB
               ON B.id = RB.id
    WHERE  (ankomst <= $ankomst AND avreise >= $ankomst)
           OR (ankomst < $avreise AND avreise >= $avreise )
           OR ($ankomst <= ankomst AND $avreise >= ankomst)
);
";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
    echo "<p>" . $row["romnummer"] . "</p>";
}
?>
```

Currently, there are only 3 rooms in my theoretical hotel. Room numer 1 is currently busy for, and therefor the query should result in roomnumber 2 & 3, which are the two rooms that are free. But when i run this code, it returns all the 3 rooms. When it should be just two. I am certain that the two dates I tested with are withing the dates of the occupied room.

The code is in norwegian, im sorry.

```
romnummer = roomnumber
bestilling = order
tilgjengelse = occupied(taken rooms)
ankomst = arrival
avreise = departure
```

Comment: The correct logic for matching overlapping periods is `startA <= endB and endA >= startB` (depending on your logic the comparisons might not be inclusive)

Comment: ...and dates generally need to be enclosed in inverted commas - but see prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a nested query have you thought about doing a left outer join with a IS NULL on b.id?

```
Select R.id
From rooms R
Left outer join orders O ON r.id = o.id
Left outer join taken T ON o.id = t.id
WHERE (<arrival and departure check>) AND O.ID IS NULL
```

That should return all rooms that do not have a match

Answer (score 0):

The logic seems to be correct at first glance, and as author mentioned, it works as expected in MSSQL console, so my guess would be that something is wrong with date conversions, try checking this. You could use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function with specific format code.

Comment: Apologies, in that case it is [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). Fixed the reply, thanks!